# Zariski's connectedness theorem applied to $V\to B$ from a surface to a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, fibration

Let all varieties over an algebraically closed field $k$ of arbitrary characteristic.

Let $f:V\to B$ be a surjective morphism where $V$ is a smooth surface and $B$ is a smooth complete curve.

I've read [here](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/%7Epubl/ln/tifr60.pdf) (2.2, page 82) that if $F$ is a singular fiber of $f$, then $F$ is connected. In the proof, the author argues that this is a consequence of "Zariski's connectedness theorem".

The only reference I could find was in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_connectedness_theorem) wikipedia article, in a statement which asks for the function field of $B$ to be "separably closed" in the function field of $V$.

I'm not sure what "separably closed" means here and the author in the first link didn't mention anything about it.

What's going on?

(by the way, I imagine that Zariski's original statement is [here](https://www.ams.org/books/memo/0005/) in chapter 6, but I couldn't have access to it)

Comment: The statement as it stands is not correct. For example, take a map $f: X\to B=\mathbb{P}^1$ with $X$ a smooth surface and at least two fibers say over $p\neq q$ are singular. Then, take a double cover $\pi:B\to B$ with $\pi(p)=\pi(q)=t$. Then, if $g=\pi\circ f$, $g^{-1}(t)$ is singular and not connected.

Comment: @Mohan You mean the first link or wikipedia?

Comment: Do you think this Zariski theorem (whatever it says originally) applies here? If not, what is missing?

Comment: Here is one version of Zariski's connectedness. If $f:X\to Y$ is a surjective morphism of irreducible projective varieties and the general fiber is irreducible, then the special fiber is connected. So, in your case, if $V\to B$ had the separably closedness condition, then general fiber is irreducible and thus special fibers are connected.